# Extracting a list from a list LINQ

Tags: c#, asp.net, list, linq

I am trying to extract a list of Goals from within a list of Students using this method

```
 public List<Goal> GetGoalsForTeacher(int userId)
        {
            var students = GetStudentsForTeacher(userId);
            var result = students.Select(e => e.Goals).ToList();
            return result

        }
```

However, I need it to return a List, but it is returning a List<IList>. Has anyone any idea on how I would convert this or make it a List initially?

Comment: I suspect that the `Goals` property of whatever class is use for 'student' is itself a `List`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're looking for the `SelectMany()` method.

```
var result = students.SelectMany(e => e.Goals).ToList();
```

Comment: woohoo it worked thank you!